# In flutter I am unable to connect to API, When I test it works well but from flutter it is not working?

Tags: flutter, api, dart

```
Future predictCluster(List<List<int>> scores) async {
String url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict';
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

Response response = await post(uri, body: (scores));
Map<String, dynamic> prediction = json.decode(response.body);
cluster = int.parse(prediction["predicted_cluster"][0]);

notifyListeners();
}
```

[Here I have to send a list of list with integers as per API but getting rejected by casting when I am using encode methods I am getting a Format exception.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2kTO.jpg)

[This is the api.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfh6x.png)

Getting Error for line
Response response = await post(uri, body: (scores));

Error:
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, probably, that your emulator doesn't reach your API on your local machine.

The url should instead be:

```
String url = 'http://10.0.2.2:5000/predict';
```

Comment: It's not working either.

Comment: Added a suggestion for type cast issue. As a tip in the future, do not add screenshots in the question. Only text. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: int.parse(prediction["predicted_cluster"][0] as String);
This is also not working either.
Is this problem occurs because of sending List<List<int>> type without having Map structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
Future predictCluster(List<List<int>> scores) async {
String url = 'http://10.0.2.2:5000/predict';

Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

final encodedData = jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
  "score": scores,
});

Response response = await post(
  uri,
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
  body: encodedData,
);
Map<String, dynamic> prediction = json.decode(response.body);
cluster = int.parse(prediction["predicted_cluster"][0]);

notifyListeners();
}
```

We have to send through the **map structure** to encode data and also mention the **header content type to application/json.**